# CSS adding stretching edges next to banner

Tags: html, css, html5-canvas

Im a beginner sitebuilder :) I want to do the following:
there is a 400x200 sized banner image, this must be put centered. As the width is bigger, there must be 2 edges left and right, preferably stretching, so:

```
s t r e t c h e d i m a g e BANNER s t r e t c h e d i m a g e

st re tc he di ma ge BANNER st re tc he di ma ge
```

the left and right images are different...
but here comes a trick. The centered IMG is width = 100%, so it must shrink when the the width of browser (iphone) is smaller than 400px... and then this two edges must be hidden!

Now how to do this? I tried to add a container div and set background-image - but it wont work, as the 2 edges are different... ideas?

Comment: Can you make a fiddle?

Comment: no I cant make a fiddle

Comment: Just so I understand...you have 3 horizontally arranged images.  When there is enough room, all 3 images are at full size.   When the browser window becomes less wide, you want to shrink the left and right images, but leave the center image fullsize.  When the browser window is 400px or less, the left and right images are not shown and the center image shrinks.  I assume that you want any image to shrink proportionally--not distorted. This means the left/right images will eventually be very tiny compared to the center.  Have I got it right?  If so, html canvas can do this using drawImage().

Comment: yepp, I want to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can use html-canvas to resize your Logo and side images**

With canvas + javascript you can respond to resizing.  You can scale down the side images as well as eliminate them as your viewport goes below 400px.

For example, here is your banner when all images will fit full-sized.

[image]

Here is your banner when the side images must be scaled down with center remaining full-sized.

[image]

And here is your banner when the sides are removed and the center must be resized.

[image]

Here is code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/JewbA/

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

  <style>
      body{ background-color: ivory; }
      #wrapper{ position:relative; }
      canvas{ position:absolute; left:40px; top:5px; border:1px solid red;}
      #amount{ position:absolute; left:1px; top:5px; margin-bottom:15px; width:23px; border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold; }
      #slider-vertical{ position:absolute; left:5px; top:40px; width:15px; height:225px; border:0px; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold; }
  </style>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

  <script>

  $(function() {

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    $( "#slider-vertical" ).slider({
      orientation: "vertical",
      range: "min",
      min: 150,
      max: 800,
      value: 800,
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#amount" ).val( ui.value );
        resizeAndDraw();
      }
    });

    $( "#amount" ).val( $( "#slider-vertical" ).slider( "value" ) );

      var imgcount=0;
      var left=new Image();
      left.onload=function(){ imgsLoaded(); }
      left.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/facebook.png";
      var center=new Image();
      center.onload=function(){ imgsLoaded(); }
      center.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/logo.png";
      var right=new Image();
      right.onload=function(){ imgsLoaded(); }
      right.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/twitter.png";
      function imgsLoaded(){
          if(++imgcount>=3){
              resizeAndDraw();
          }
      }

      var offsetY=10;

      function resizeAndDraw(){

          var width=$("#amount").val();

          canvas.width=width;

          var centerWidth=(width>center.width)?center.width:width;
          var centerHeight=center.height*centerWidth/center.width;
          var centerX=width/2-centerWidth/2;
          var centerY=offsetY;

          var sidesWidth=(width-centerWidth)/2;

          var leftWidth=(sidesWidth>left.width)?left.width:sidesWidth;
          var leftHeight=left.height*leftWidth/left.width;
          var leftX=sidesWidth/2-leftWidth/2;
          var leftY=offsetY+centerHeight/2-leftHeight/2;

          var rightWidth=(sidesWidth>right.width)?right.width:sidesWidth;
          var rightHeight=right.height*rightWidth/right.width;
          var rightX=(width/2+centerWidth/2)+(sidesWidth/2-rightWidth/2);
          var rightY=offsetY+centerHeight/2-rightHeight/2;

          // center
          ctx.drawImage(center,centerX,centerY,centerWidth,centerHeight);

          if(width>400){
              // left
              ctx.drawImage(left,leftX,leftY,leftWidth,leftHeight);
              // right
              ctx.drawImage(right,rightX,rightY,rightWidth,rightHeight);
          }
      }

  });   // end $(function(){});

  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <input type="text" id="amount" />
        <div id="slider-vertical"></div>
        <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but may be you can try putting the z-index to the stretchedimage, so it goes to the background. The banner gets displayed over the images.

z-index:-1;

Comment: yes, thats so far so good... but as I said, I cant use background image. The edges at the left and right are different

Comment: img
{
position:absolute;
left:0px;
top:0px;
z-index:-1;
}

Comment: is it not ok to join the left and right image into one image and use it as a background. It has to appear only when the banner width is less than the screen ??

Comment: nope, because the two edges are different (left ends with green color, other ends with red)